# How can hook up to address bar of IE, by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was wondering of how can I get the enter key press when someone presses in address bar of IE?
for example:
http://www.test.com/#/contanct/ and I would like to press enter and reload it?
The IE doesn't trigger reload cycle after enter is pressed without changing the any of the values within the address bar.
In Chrome this behavior is build in, how can I simulate the same behavior?

Comment: Any JavaScript loaded in the current page has - to the best of my knowledge - no access to the browser chrome (the addres bar, the buttons) whatsoever as a security precaution. There may be IE vulnerabilities that allow this, but if there are they shouldn't be taken advantage of and should be reported to be patched. Possibly you could set a localStorage variable to the time the page was unloaded (using `onbeforeunload`) and if that variable is less than 5s (arbitrary figure) older than the current time simply assume the page was refreshed either by pressing enter or using F5..?

Comment: @DavidThomas I know this, but what are my possibilities?

Comment: @DavidThomas It's some kind of hack and not much reliable. How can I do it bullet proof?

Comment: Y​o​u​ c​a​n​'​t.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ok. Thanks. Then I would be required to write a addin for IE